# How do I use IQKeyboard in such a way that it doesn't hide the validation texts too?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am using IQKeyboard (https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) to avoid keyboard hiding the textfields while writing on them. However they hide validation texts below it (which is obvious). How do I avoid the same too?

I am using the following code in AppDelegate on an order to use the IQKeyboard:

```
 IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
 IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enableAutoToolbar = false
 IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().shouldShowToolbarPlaceholder = false
 IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().previousNextDisplayMode = IQPreviousNextDisplayMode.alwaysHide
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `keyboardDistanceFromTextField` to add distance between keyboard and textfield.

Example:

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().keyboardDistanceFromTextField = 40
```